# I would like to add user id to the note annotated to the cell. I this possible>? I am raw to apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function onEditNote() {
  
  // get spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('MCD Current Stock');
  
  // get active cell
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  
  // get any existing cell value
  var currentCellValue = activeCell.getValue();
  Logger.log('Current cell value is: ' + currentCellValue);
  
  // get any existing cell Note
  var currentCellNote = activeCell.getNote();
  Logger.log('Current Note contains: ' + currentCellNote);
  
  // set Note on the edited cell with above information
  activeCell.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date() + '\n' + 'Cell value: ' + "'" + currentCellValue + "'" + '\n\n' + currentCellNote);
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requires an installable onEdit trigger

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  //sh.getRange('A1').setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
  if (sh.getName() == 'MCD Current Stock') {
    //e.source.toast('sheet');
    let note = e.range.getNote();
    let user = Session.getUser().getEmail();
    if (note != '') {
      //e.source.toast('note')
      e.range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date() + '\n' + 'User: ' + "'" + user + ' Cell value: ' + "'" + e.value + "'" + '\n\n' + note);
    } else {
      e.range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date() + '\n' + 'User: ' + "'" + user + ' Cell value: ' + "'" + e.value + "'")
    }
  }
}
```

Only works when cell is edited and not when note attached to cell is edited.

Comment: Thanks for this but it didn't pass through de-bug.9:14:17 AM Notice Execution started
9:14:18 AM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onMyEdit @ Code.gs:3

Comment: You cannot run this code from the script editor without providing the event object.  Typically, I debug these scripts by running them as I edit the page.  If you will notice, I've left all of my debug lines in the code but commented out.  With those and perhaps the occasional use of Logger I debug the code.

Comment: appreciate the help. I will get there.